# Toolbox/framework to construct lightweight public-facing web site

Tags: php, web-applications, web

I am aware of full-blown content management systems (CMS) such as SugarCRM and TikiWiki... where content is typically stored in a database... and edited through the same interface as it is published.  While I like many of the features, the product is clearly aimed at enterprise-wide use rather than to be public-facing.

What I'd like to establish are potential alternatives that fill the space between full-blown CMS and hand-coded bespoke site.  I like the way that I can add modules to my CMS... allowing me to quickly introduce new functionality, and I'd like an analogous feature in a system for public web-content.  Modules I know I'd like include moderated comments; web-form-to-email gateway; menus/tabs... in future, perhaps mapping or diaries or RSS integration - etc.

Where my requirements differ from a CMS, I don't need (or want) most content to be editable through the main site... and, somehow, I do want to be able to preview how updates will be presented to the public rather than to make live changes.  For these purposes, in contrast to those where a typical CMS would be ideal, presentation is of paramount importance - and trumps any desire to immediately disseminate information.

I realise that this is a very high-level question... (suggestions of additional tags welcome) - I mentioned PHP only as - ideally - I'm looking for an open source solution and a PHP deployment is an easy option.

What are my options?

Comment: Sounds to me you're actually looking for a framework, rather then a CMS, perhaps Zend is one you might want to look into

Comment: Your looking for a framework, you could use Zend or codeigniter but there is a learning curve, alternatively you could create your own small lightweight MVC framework in under an hour, assuming you have some knowledge of PHP

Comment: A framework might well be what I want... Zend is one possibility - though it is lower-level than I had hoped for.  On reflection, this idea that I can preview the site each time it is amended, before it goes live, is a key requirement... and I'd really like any approach I select to explicitly support this.  I'm capable, but I'd like to avoid rolling my own - if possible... :)

Comment: I don't know if you want a full framework like Zend, Symfony or CodeIgniter. But it seems that you just want a sort of API that is high level. Perhaps a "microframework" like Silex would be what you want. perhaps you just want something that is based on the concept of "bundle" like Symfony2 but with less "default provided" fonctionality.??

Answer (score 1):

This question is the sort that can spark religious wars.  Since you aren't asking a coding or programming question, it can't be answered with fact, only with opinion.

In my experience, [Symfony](http://www.symfony.com/) has always done well as a framework, following MVC architecture.  As with any framework, developing a site using Symfony requires greater commitment and a lot more programming than would be required with a CMS.

I see you want a preview option.  While you could do that yourself with Symfony, you might want to take advantage of that functionality within [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) instead, using its [workflow module](http://drupal.org/project/workflow).  Of course, using Drupal's roles, you can make certain pages (or types of page) unavailable for modification.

There are many many ways to implement your requirements.  The more research you do, the less likely you'll be to have to backtrack and re-write things.

**UPDATE**:

The best resources for learning Symfony are found on [Symfony.com](http://symfony.com/).  Visit the [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) section.  "*The Book*" is a general resource on All Things Symfony, and I believe it's the most authoritative and complete resource you'll find.**  I find it clear and well-written.  "*The Cookbook*" contains examples and strategies for particular types of applications, and is more useful once you're comfortable using Symfony.

** <sub>When you're selecting books from Symfony.com, on the right-hand side of the page, you'll see a Select box saying "2.0 version".  While 2.0 is the latest "release" of Symfony, you might want to change this to "master version", which will include references to features to be included in the upcoming 2.1 release.  Symfony releases tend to be pretty radically different from previous version, so it will be good to develop for what will be "release" by the time you finish your project.</sub>

Each of the books can be downloaded as a PDF.  All the books from Sensio Labs (creators of Symfony) are licensed under Creative Commons.

As for add-on software, Sensio has released a number of add-ons (called "bundles" in Symfony-speak).  These are documented on the same site, but third-party bundles, of which there are many, have documentation generally provided by their authors.  You can find a library of open source bundles at http://knpbundles.com/.

As for Drupal, I must admit that I generally implement things in Drupal more than Symfony these days.  With command-line management using [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush), it's extremely easy to keep up-to-date, and the Drupal software and module maintainers are friendly and easy to find in IRC (on FreeNode).  Drupal has a HUGELY extensive collection of online documentation.  It can be a bit daunting, actually, but things tend to be pretty well organized.  There are a number of books that have been published on Drupal, and may be listed at http://drupal.org/books ... but I haven't ready any, so I can't make specific recommendations.

Without knowing more about your requirements, I can only recommend both Drupal and Symfony.  :)

Comment: It's because there are a lot of potential strategies that I opted to post the question... I'm interested to establish the options (I'm rarely involved with GUI/Web development myself - I tend to focus on systems level development.)  I feel I need something between a web-framework and an end-user CMS. I was aware of Symphony, but unless there's an extensive library of CPAN-like modules... I'm not sure it's right for this project.  I will look into Drupal again... especially the work-flow module...

Comment: for Symfony you have lots of bundles already written. Have a look at KNPBundles and FriendOfSymfony Bundles. FOSUserBundle, KnpBlogBundle are well known.

Comment: Symphony looks more and more promising.  Can you recommend a good book on it? All I can find is the "The Definitive Guide to Symfony" - but that was published Jan 2007 - so, I expect, it might be out of date?

Comment: Added some book references to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need (or want) most content to be editable through the main site...

So you don't need (or want) a CMS.

You need to code the thing that you want yourself. You can, however, get help from existing tools. There are lot of API, frameworks, microframeworks... that can help you to do such things.

At first, do you accept to write your code with MVC. If not, the only tool I know is CakePHP.

If yes :
I noticed you wanted :

> I like the way that I can add modules to my CMS... allowing me to quickly introduce new functionality, and I'd like an analogous feature in a system for public web-content.

So a framework with an easy "plug-n-play like" architecture would be fun. My experience with Symfony makes me say it is good for you. 
for Symfony you have lots of bundles already written. Have a look at KNPBundles and FriendOfSymfony Bundles. FOSUserBundle, KnpBlogBundle are well known
But I also see that :

> A framework might well be what I want... Zend is one possibility - though it is lower-level than I had hoped for.

So I can tell you about Silex, a microframework that is based on Symfony core (so it is a high level with no greedy extension) and its bundles architecture.

I also heard about hoa_project (because I follow its creator on twitter) but never used it so I can't tell you more.

Comment: I'm not phased by writing MVC code - as an architecture, it's fine... but really I want high-level high-quality components that I can glue-together.  Silex sounds interesting - though it doesn't seem to focus on high-level user-oriented components... I'm trying to find out more about Symfony "bundles"...

Comment: Symfony CMF looks promising - https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox - my only reservation is that I want to ensure that changes to the public facing site are reviewed before going live... I love the look and feel of the live sandbox demo.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements you list are, in fact, those of a CMS. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want:

- Content-oriented modules (article, comment, moderation, web forms etc.)
- WYSIWYG preview prior to publish
- The ability to create (or re-use) modules
- A high degree of control over the presentation layer.

What you don't want is:

- "in-page" editing of content

There are many PHP content management systems which meet these requirements; I'm personally familiar with [CMS Made Simple](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/) which has pretty much all the above. Drupal is a more fully featured (and complex) option which also offers this. Wordpress is a big favourite with those who need to build nice-looking sites in a hurry.

All these CMS solutions are focused at producing public-facing websites, rather than intranet knowledge sharing applications (they're pretty useless at that). Drupal provides workflow which allows you to manage the content publication workflow. The key thing they provide which is non-trivial to build from scratch is a way of providing "WYSIWYG" previews of content.

The major drawback with these options in my view is that they are great for content driven sites, but if you want to integrate functionality into the application, or tinker with the layout, you have to work through the CMS layer which wants to control the user interface; this can become a little tiresome.

Comment: Essentially, I'm looking for a content publishing system - rather than a content management system, per se.  I'm (almost exclusively) concerned by the public facing access... which will (predominantly) be read-only and support anonymous access.  CMS systems, to me, seem to focus on managing information within an organisation - I want to manage the information an organisation publishes... I'd be happy for the content itself to be managed by an separate system.

Comment: I don't think the two examples you mention in your question are classic CMS solutions - they're certainly not right for building public-facing websites. I still don't quite see why tools such as Drupal, CMSMS and Wordpress don't meet your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost describing [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). See this the [video](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/) [demonstrations](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) and decide if this is what you need. CodeIgniter is not a CMS but rather a framework in which you can easily build a CMS that suits your exact needs.

Comment: Code igniter looks a capable framework - but, like Zend, it is lower-level than I'd hoped for... I'd like to have standard blocks for 'blog-entry'; 'moderated, approved-only, comments'; 'contact-site form' - etc.  Sure, I could write my own - but that feels like re-inventing the wheel.  I'd like slick implementations of fairly-mainstream concepts... and to be able to glue them together myself... only writing code to manage databases/html/javascript generation if/when I need genuinely original behaviour.

Comment: I see. I would say that CodeIgniter is a bit higher-level than Zend but yes, you will have to reinvent your own wheels! I mention CodeIgniter as you may not find any CMS with the unique features that you need but CodeIgniter will help you code up what you need rather easily. More importantly, it will be very maintainable so that you can add or change features easily in the future when you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add Yii (http://www.yiiframework.com/). A great framework with all sorts of lighten-your-programming features. A preview feature is not on-board, but not hard to add (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.0/en/post.create#implementing-preview-feature).